# How to redirect to new ID of a url

Tags: python, html, mysql

I'm using flask form. When i run the code below to paste the new data to test.html, it returned the url of '/team1/test/[0]' but not '/team1/test/1'. Please help. Thanks.

```
@application.route('/team1/test/<mid>')
def result(mid):
cursor = g.db_conn.cursor()
sql_stmt = """
SELECT  id, first_name, last_name, grade from table1
where id = %s;
"""
scores = [dict(id=row[0], first_name=row[1], last_name=row[2]) for row in      cursor.fetchall()]
if len(scores) > 0:
    score = scores[0]
else:
    score = None
cursor.execute(sql_stmt, (id,))
```